# run a text block from command line

Tags: python, command-line

using this command `blender --help` to get more help about Blender command line options, you can find this snippet

> `--python-text <name>
>       Run the given Python script text block`

So if I'm not wrong, this means that I can specify the name of text block which I would like to auto run at Blender start.

So my final command will look like this:
`blender --python-text my_text_block_name scene.blend`

Where "my_text_block_name" is the name of text block I wrote and save right in my blend file.

But, when I run this command, I have the following error.

> Error: text block not found my_text_block_name.

What I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
I'm using the latest official version of Blender for linux 64bit available at this moment (2.76)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike most command line programs the order of the options make a difference. The thing to remember is that blender executes each option in the order they are given, almost like a mini script.

The command you used `blender --python-text my_text_block_name scene.blend` says run this text block then open this file.

To get your example working you want to open the blend file then execute the text block - `blender scene.blend --python-text my_text_block_name`

[More details about Blender command](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html)
and some [example of how order works](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#argument-order).

Comment: I tested it and you're right, order matters. Do you know where to find more official info about this or this is just "user experience" :) ?

Comment: It is documented in [the manual](http://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line.html#argument-order), but doesn't really give a lot more info.