# Running a python script with arguments in blender from terminal

Tags: python, command-line

I want to run a python script for a blend file within blender and I want to give the command from terminal. Blender has this option as follows:

```
blender -b -P python_script_path.py
```

But I want to pass some command line arguments to the python script. Is it possible to do this? If yes, how?

Comment: Does [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6817/42221) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. Run an inline python script that will call a string and run it as it's own shell command.

```
# test_run.py
# The test file to run.

import sys

arg1 = sys.argv[1]
arg2 = sys.argv[2]

if __name__ == "__main__":
        string = f"""
        Argument 1: {arg1}
        Argument 2: {arg2}
        """
        print(string)
```

Then the command that you would  in the terminal. If you wanted to run that script alone, with it's two arguments.

`python3 ~/scripts/random/test_run.py first_arg second_arg`

So then use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module, which allows you to call shell commands from within python. Throw that into the blender command line with the argument `--python-text` and you should get.

```
blender -b --python-expr "import subprocess; subprocess.run('python3 ~/scripts/random/test_run.py first_arg second_arg', shell=True)"
```

You might have to change the part that says `python3` to the python that runs natively with blender. I'm running a custom install of blender and I haven't configured the command line to run as normal, it's just a symlink to the .exe so I'm not sure about the exact specifics of running it in the Blender specific python environment.

But I think the mechanics of how to do it are all there.

Comment: Thanks! This is amazing :)

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but I'm getting the following error: `Error: text block not found import subprocess; subprocess.run('python PropertiesSetter.py depth optical_flow surface_normals positions', shell=True)`. Any idea why I'm getting this error? Also, in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/41251/101146), the argument python-text specifies the name of python code already written into the blend file. So, I'm wondering if specifying code would actually work.

Comment: @NagabhushanSN You can execute Python from the Blender command line using `--python-expr <expression>`  See [Python Options](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#python-options) in the manual.  You have to be very careful with command line quoting.

Comment: Lol yep, I glazed over it and put the wrong line in my answer. Updated.